# How to check if Windows Server 2008 R2 is using TLS 1.2 for communications?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl

I've been trying to figure out if my IIS server is using TLS 1.2 for communication since an API I connect to is disabling access for TLS 1.1 next month. Everything I've found on the web is telling me out to edit the registry to enable 1.2 communication, but I want to verify if it is already using it first.

Is there a way, without using regedit to verify if a server is communicating over TLS 1.2?

Comment: Are you familiar with Wireshark? If you can install Wireshark on either the IIS server or a client, Wireshark can parse the traffic and tell you which version of TLS is being used. Examples: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142939/determine-ssl-tls-version-using-wireshark and https://blog.catchpoint.com/2017/05/12/dissecting-tls-using-wireshark/

Comment: Chrome will tell you on the Developer Tools under Security, while Firefox will tell you both in it's Developer tools and from the Site Security view accessed by clicking on the padlock in the address bar.  IE/Edge may have similar tools.

Comment: Attempt to connect to something that only supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: Doesn't this depend on how exactly you are using the API in question?  For example, for a client-side javascript API, it is presumably the client's TLS support that counts, not your server's.